# Have any CLR functions been defined on data explorer that allow regex searches?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

There are some searches that you just can't do without regex support, but...

AFAIK SQL Server doesn't support regex, but [support can be added by creating CLR functions](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/).

Has this been done?

If so, what are the function names?
If not, can it be done?

Of course, any such functions that exist should be noted on the [help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: You can use patindex like I did here: Use this https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173097/longest-post-for-amal-murali  not regex but it gives you a little bit more capabilities if a simple like pattern doesn't work in unstructured texts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CLR is not enabled on the SEDE SQL Server instance, and won't be for security and performance reasons.

Comment: And there's no other way to do regex (I'm not an SQL Server aficionado)?

Comment: @Bohemian You can do string matches, but no regex patterns, no - not in the current version.

Comment: And doing pretty much all string operations on Stack Overflow's `Posts` table is prohibitively expensive anyway, unless you can narrow down your search space first.

Comment: What about the API, Nick? Any way to filter by regex in there?

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope, we do not (nor do most sane) allow arbitrary regexes to be run on our servers.

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @NickCraver - I don't see that allowing arbitrary regex's is any more dangerous than allowing arbitrary SQL. A badly written query could consume a lot of resources anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith that's why queries have a MaxDOP and timeout set.

Comment: But the timeout would cancel any queries with catastrophically back tracking regex's too.

Comment: @MartinSmith the CLR engine has different constraints, it's not an immediate cleanup. You can argue how "not *that* bad" it is if you want, but that's not a great argument for it. What *would* you want to regex against? It's almost always the post bodies, which would timeout anyway.

Comment: Yep. Good point.