# Why does data explorer not support ILIKE, SIMILAR TO, or regular expressions (~)?

Tags: support, data-explorer, sql, regex

Why does the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) not support `ILIKE`, `SIMILAR TO`, or regular expressions `~`?

Talking to the devs:
Would it be possible to add that functionality?

Comment: The whole Stack Exchange platform is based on Windows and MSSQL; those functions do not exist in MSSQL. Still, as SEDE does not *directly* execute queries, it should be possible to 'emulate' that functionality.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Data Explorer isn't backed by PostgreSQL, but a SQL Server instance, and those functions aren't defined in T-SQL. While it would be possible to allow regex [via CLR functions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224832/have-any-clr-functions-been-defined-on-data-explorer-that-allow-regex-searches), that isn't something that will be added.

`ILIKE` should be generally easily emulated using `LOWER(column) LIKE …` though, where the acceptable pattern characters can be found in the [`LIKE` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Comment: Instead of `Lower` you can use [collate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) as well: `where title like '%Function%'  collate Latin1_General_100_ci_ai` as shown [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/354312)

Answer (score 7):

Outside of the aforementioned `LIKE` clause, `PATINDEX` is the only pattern matching function. The following are supported by both `PATINDEX` and `LIKE`:

```
Wildcard Specification      Description
%                           Matches zero of more characters
_                           Matches any single character
[]                          Matches a range [A-Z] or a set [!@#$%^&*(){}|]
[^]                         Excludes a range or a set as noted above
```

**References**

- [PATINDEX function](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Patindex.htm)
- [Matching Character Strings: like](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/san1390612129997.html)

Comment: That's not true a standard LIKE supports limited pattern matching in SQL Server: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8928378/458741

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards `The only pattern matching function is PATINDEX`. `LIKE` is not a function, so the statement is true.

Comment: @PaulSweatte: Your *assertion* is true, but the *implication* is misleading, especially given that the assertion narrows the scope of the question without clearly excluding the rest of it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sorry. I was just covering what was not mentioned in the previous answer. Is that narrowing the scope of the question, given that the existing answer refers to `LIKE`?

Comment: @PaulSweatte: The question doesn't really limit itself to functions. It's concerned only with getting some sort of built-in support for pattern matching; whether that be syntactically a "function" or something else is beside the point.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for the clarification. I've updated the answer with context.